# not get name after space in asp.net in visual studio

Tags: asp.net

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    sb.Append("<img src=news.gif> </img><a href="+"Doc/"+rdr[1].ToString()+" target=_blank onclick=counterfunction("+rdr[2]+")>"+rdr[0].ToString()+"</a>");

sb.Append("<br/>");
}
```

/* for example 
i want to save image name abhi shek.jpg but these hyperlink only get abhi after space not
get anything pls solve these problem */

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're writing `href=foo bar.jpg` instead of `href='foo bar.jpg'`

Just include the ' marks.

Answer (score 0):

URLs have to be properly percent-encoded to conform to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.4). Space is not a valid character in the URL path, so it must be encoded.

What that boils down to for you is that you must use [`HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) every time you write an URL in your response.